# How do I test for separate means in a small nested data set?

Tags: small-sample, nested-data

My observations are grouped into 3 groups, each of these 3 groups has 2 subgroups, I have 2 observations from each subgroup.

Each group appears quite well divided from each other group, and each subgroup is quite well divided from each other subgroup.

I have tried matlabs anova1 and multcompare, but as they don't allow for nesting the results weren't useful. The Anovan function was good but there is no program equivalent to multcompare for nested datasets.

I have also been looking through R documentation but haven't found anything useful yet.

Comment: Your description sounds like a split-plot design. There are traditional specialized ANOVA models for that, or you could fit a mixed effects model for that. Although I haven't used MATLAB in years, I'm sure it has methods for those. Bear in mind that asking for code is off topic here, though.